# Bad file name error in Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I sometimes got this message when I upload PFFile to User class:

```
[Error]: Bad file name: profileImage.png (Code: 122, Version: 1.13.0)
```

Here is the code

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profileImageView.image);
PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"profileImage.png" data:imageData];
currentUser[@"profileImageFile"] = imageFile;
    [currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(!succeeded){
            NSLog(@"error:%@",error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Is this really bad file name? Someone go well to upload PFFile with this file name.

Comment: Could you please revise your question to improve the explanation?

Comment: please check at which line the error is coming